# Using a decorator on a method while keeping binding to `this`

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

When using method syntax how can you use a decorator and keep the binding to `this`?

```js
{
  getFieldId: _.curry(function (index, fieldName) {
    // this is not bound
    return `${this.getPrefix()}${this.lowerCaseName}-${index}-${fieldName}`
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

```js
{
  getFieldId: _.curry((index, fieldName) => {
    return `${this.getPrefix()}${this.lowerCaseName}-${index}-${fieldName}`
  })
}
```

Arrow functions bind `this` context lexically.

Comment: This doesn't work because `this` will be bound to the global object.  I looked a little deeper and the way I had it is correct except that `_.curry()` is written to send `undefined` as `this` so what I want cannot be done at least with this version of curry.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an ES6 arrow function should work:

```
getFieldId: _.curry((index, fieldName) => `${this.getPrefix()}${this.lowerCaseName}-${index}-${fieldName}`)
```

Or more verbose with a block function:

```
getFieldId: _.curry((index, fieldName) => {
    return `${this.getPrefix()}${this.lowerCaseName}-${index}-${fieldName}`
})
```